# Create Multiple Factories for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Earlier I was having single factory for user and it worked fine.

But now, I want two sets of factories for user's data , one with encrypted details and other one with plain text user details.

This is the code I am using:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
   trait :encryption do 
    email                 AESCrypt.encrypt(Faker::Internet.email, ENV["AES_KEY"])
    password              AESCrypt.encrypt("password", ENV["AES_KEY"])
    password_confirmation AESCrypt.encrypt("password",ENV["AES_KEY"])
    username              Faker::Name.name 
    end

   trait :unencrypted_user_details do
    email                 Faker::Internet.email
    password              "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    username              Faker::Name.name 
   end
 end
end
```

And using the same as in spec file:

```
user = FactoryBot.create(:user,:unencrypted_user_details)
```

But I am getting the following error while running the spec:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `name=' for #<User:0x00000006d512f8>
```

The User model does not have a field "name" instead "username" is there.

Error Stacktrace:

```
 F
```

Failures:

1) Api::V2::UserApp::UsersController Generate Pin API generates a new pin for the user
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryBot.create(:unencrypted_user_details)

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `name=' for #<User:0x0000000664cbb0>
   Did you mean?  name
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `public_send'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:13:in `object'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
 # /home/xxxxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
 # ./spec/controllers/user_app/users_controller.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.37745 seconds (files took 4.26 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure

user_spec.rb

```
 describe "Generate Pin API" do
  it "generates a new pin for the user" do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:unencrypted_user_details)  #line 43

    client = user.client

    request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = user.auth_token

    get :generate_pin

    response_json = JSON.parse(response.body)

    expect(response_json["response_code"]).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

Controller Code

```
def generate_pin
phone = ValidatePhone.find_by(phone_no: @client.phone_no)

phone.present? ? phone.update_attributes(is_verified: true) : ValidatePhone.create(phone_no: @client.phone_no)
sms_text = "Hello"
send_sms(@client.phone_no,sms_text)
render :json => {
        :response_code => 200,
        :response_message => "Welcome Onboard."
    }
```

end

Is this the correct way to create multiple factories and why am I getting this error undefined method name?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this the correct way to create multiple factories and why am I getting this error undefined method name?

Comment: Faker::Name.name ?

Comment: Add full error trace, please

Comment: Faker::Name.name is correct..I am getting error when running        user = FactoryBot.create(:user,:unencrypted_user_details)

Comment: @Vasilisa..added  stack trace for reference

Comment: Try to run `rails db:test:prepare` before your test

Comment: Still facing the same issue

Comment: What does this line `spec/controllers/user_app/users_controller.rb:43` contain?

Comment: Also add the relevant test to the question

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Added relavant user_spec in the question

Comment: Also the controller code please.

Comment: Hmm, should you use `FactoryBot.create(:user, :unencrypted_user_details)` ?

Comment: @Rohan if you run the same test with a simple user factory (without trait) it's working ?

Comment: @sovalina..yes working with simple user factory(without trait)

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk..there is need to create a user first then send an sms on the user onboarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to create variable factories. You must use brackets for fields on which value is the result fo a call:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
   trait :encryption do 
    email    { AESCrypt.encrypt(Faker::Internet.email, ENV["AES_KEY"]) }
    password { AESCrypt.encrypt("password", ENV["AES_KEY"]) }
    password_confirmation { AESCrypt.encrypt("password",ENV["AES_KEY"]) }
    username { Faker::Name.name }
  end

  trait :unencrypted_user_details do
    email                 { Faker::Internet.email }
    password              "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    username              { Faker::Name.name }
   end
 end
end
```

Take a look at the guides: 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits